# Change an Image to Byte, for file *within* project

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, byte

Long story short: I want to put an image in a column of a DataTable.  To do this, I've gathered from various other sources that I need to convert the image to bytes, and then assign the bytes to the desired DataRow column.

So I've got pretty much exactly what I need, EXCEPT, all the guides I've found are for referencing files on the system.  The image I need to convert is within the project.

Here's what I have, abbreviated:

```
DataColumn amountcol = new DataColumn();
amountcol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");
//...
newrow = dt.NewRow();
newrow[amountcol] = ReadImage("images/dashboard/myvacstatus-am.png", new string[] { ".png" });
```

---

```
private static byte[] ReadImage(string p_postedImageFileName, string[] p_fileType)
{
    bool isValidFileType = false;

    try
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(p_postedImageFileName);

        foreach (string strExtensionType in p_fileType)
        {
            if (strExtensionType == file.Extension)
            {
                isValidFileType = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isValidFileType)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(p_postedImageFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return image;
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

---

**The problem: it looks for the file on the system, and not within the project.**

I get the following error:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\images\dashboard\myvacstatus-ampm.png'.

Comment: What do you mean of within the project? Do you mean it's inside the resource file?

Comment: I mean that, in my project, I have a folder called "images," and the file is within that folder.  The project may move around from computer to computer, so I need to be able to reference that folder in the project.

Comment: you need to get the complete path using Server.MapPath()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the path from which you are reading the image is valid.

**UPDATE**

Get the complete path using the following code.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("images/dashboard/myvacstatus-am.png")
```

Comment: Thanks, Server.MapPath solved my problem of being able to locate the file from within the project.  Having a bit of trouble still getting it to show up in the DataTable, but that's a question for another day :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute (i.e., fully qualified) path rather than the un-rooted relative path you have specified ("images/dashboard/myvacstatus-am.png").

You probably shouldn't try to read the file from the project folder hierarchy.  Instead, specify that the files be deployed to the deployment directory (or a sub folder), and read them from there.  Otherwise, you'll run into trouble if you distribute the application to non-developer users.

Comment: As the project may move around from computer to computer (it may be on the C:\ drive on my computer, but on the D:\ on my co-workers computer), I need to keep the path relative.

Comment: @CptSupermarket that's fine, but you need to keep in mind that it's relative to *something*, and you need a way of controlling what that something is. See the edited answer for one idea.

Comment: We're not even near close to a deployment stage or anything like that.  Everything is subject to change.  Hardcoding in some arbitrary path seems like it would be really easy to forget to change, as the project moves around from computer to computer.

Comment: No no no don't hard code a path.  The application is deployed *every time you debug it,* so deploy the file to some path relative to the exe file, and go from there.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  Sorry, I just started and this is my first project, so I'm not too familiar with the deployment process :) Definitely soon I need to learn sooner rather than later.  Thanks.

Comment: Look in the file properties page in VS ... right-click the file in solution explorer and choose ”properties”

Answer (score 0):

In order to look for the file in the web application folder structure you can user `Server.MapPath("/relative/url/tofile.png")`.

That will find the file and you can read it into memory and do what need to be done with it. But just assigning the resulting `byte[]` to the data source for the DataList will not cause an image to be shown.

In order to show the image you will need to:

- Add an `<img ... />` tag in the correct place in the `DataList`
- The `src` attribute of the image should point to a place where the image data can be found

Based on the setup you have (you explicitly say that the file is within the project) you should be able to use something like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="image_myvacstatus" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="~/images/dashboard/myvacstatus-am.png" />
```

No need to load it into memory and assign to the data source for the ListView.

If you need to determine which image to show based on some other data for each row, then you can add the correct image name in the data source before databinding and use:

```
<asp:Image ID="image_myvacstatus" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/dashboard/" + (string)Eval("imageName") %>' />
```